# CRTP + variadic template + extract CRTP subclass parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, crtp

Im currently implementing a generic event class. Event handlers have a sender parameter and a variable number of event args. So the declaration of the event class is as bellow:

```
template<typename SENDER , typename... ARGS>
class event;
```

To allow certain implementation details, I need a CRTP of the event, like this:

```
template<typename SENDER , typename... ARGS>
class event : public CRTPBase<event<SENDER,ARGS...>> { ... };
```

And the CRTP base needs to know the event parameters. So I have tried with a template template param:

```
template<typename SENDER , template<typename SENDER , typename... ARGS> class EVENT, typename ARGS>
class CRTPBase { ... };
```

But this doesn't work (Im using GCC 4.8.1).

So: **What is the best way to extract the variadic and non-variadic template parameters of the argument of a CRTP?**

**EDIT:** Another way is to provide event parameters directly through the CRTP template (`template<typename EVENT , typename EVENT_SENDER , typename... EVENT_ARGS> class CRTPBase;` ), but I think there is a way to do this directly, without writting the params in a explicit way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could leave the primary template of `CRTPBase` undefined:

```
template<typename T> class CRTPBase;
```

And then partially specialize it this way:

```
template<template<typename, typename...> class TT, 
    typename SENDER, typename... ARGS>
class CRTPBase<TT<SENDER, ARGS...>>
{
    // ...
};
```

Here is a simple program that shows the type arguments could be retrieved in `CRTPBase`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T> class CRTPBase;

template<template<typename, typename...> class TT,
    typename SENDER, typename... ARGS>
class CRTPBase<TT<SENDER, ARGS...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<SENDER, ARGS...>;
};

template<typename SENDER , typename... ARGS>
class event : public CRTPBase<event<SENDER,ARGS...>>
{
    // ...
};

struct X { };

int main()
{
    event<X, int, double> e;

    // This assertion will not fire!
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        decltype(e)::type,
        std::tuple<X, int, double>
        >::value, "!");
}
```

Here is the corresponding [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked/.com/view?id=c6d37524130f2d04643fb52059ba9e3a-70854cb7d61c5b883318b4d11e427bb9).

Comment: I have tried this, but I don't know why it didn't work :( But thanks

Comment: Why will the assertion not fire?

Comment: It is not supposed to fire.  Why would you expect it?  event<X,int,double>::type really is a tuple<X,int,double> so they are the same type.  The only reason this wouldn't compile is because type is private and thus not accessible from main.